# Why are columns equal height in Bootstrap 4 and not in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Consider these basic and identical Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 samples. When inside the same row, in Bootstrap 3 `divA` seems to take as much vertical space as needed based on its own contents, whereas in Bootstrap 4 `divA` spans vertically as tall as `divB` is depending on its content.

Is there a way in Bootstrap 3 to make `divA` act like in v4+? How can you make two `div`s inside the same row have the same (not fixed) height?

I've read about the breakpoint changes in Bootstrap 4+ but I can't find any info on why these work differently.

Am I missing something?

```css
#divA {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#divB {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6" id="divA">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" id="divB">
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

```css
#divA {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#divB {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="divA">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="divB">
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 employs [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/). It's quite a different animal from earlier versions, which you can see by simply examining these snippets in your browser's inspector. Rather than asking for a guidebook on the differences, I'd revise to ask about your actual problem, which I assume to be achieving a particular layout in BS4.

Comment: I see, thanks. The problem is that we are on v3 and I need divA to act like it does in v4+, that is, both divs inside a row to be of the same (not fixed) height.

Comment: "*Why are columns equal height in Bootstrap 4 and not in Bootstrap 3?*" - Because Bootstrap 3 uses floats and Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox

Comment: You'll have to manually implement flexbox. Shanu's answer below does that while using Bootstrap classes for future compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use flex.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.a {
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla soluta corporis, repellat architecto error voluptatibus neque vitae tempora laudantium saepe nostrum sint ipsam dignissimos recusandae magnam illo eveniet veritatis! Unde.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea to use Bootstrap 4 classes. You might also use `w-30` for the width.